# ActionResult ou JsonResult retornando Json?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Vejo muitos códigos no `Controller` onde é utilizado como método `ActionResult` retornando `Json()`, mas também vejo uma abordagem utilizando como método o `JsonResult` logicamente retornando `Json`.

Por acaso há alguma diferença entre essas duas abordagens? Existe um padrão correto a se utilizar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na classe `JsonResult` temos uma herança de `ActionResult`:

```
public class JsonResult : ActionResult
```

Se você escolhe retornar um `JsonResult` você terá que retornar **APENAS** `JsonResult`, escolhendo a abordagem `ActionResult` você tem mais flexibilidade para retornar uma `Action` **OU** `JSON` pois uma `Action` é um `ActionResult` e `JSON` também pois herda `ActionResult`.

Na minha opinião é bom utilizar `ActionResult` quando você tem a chance de retornar uma `Action` **OU** `JSON`. Caso tenha certeza que o retorno deve ser sempre `JSON` utilize `JsonResult`.

Comment: Não seria o contrario ? já que JsonResult herda de ActionResult ....

Comment: entendi, vi na documentação que ActionResult é uma classe abstract.